# Can't update the DOM until I run the function for a second time. Trying to assign x to the filepath of the file selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, dom

Whenever I click the button addImage, it runs the function below and my goal is to have it update the variable x but it won't update the variable on the first time the function is ran. However once I click the addImage button again, x is then updated and I am just confused as to why it isn't updating on when the function is ran the first time.

```
<input type="button" value="&#9776" id="centerText" />
<input type="button" value="&#128279;" id="addLink" />
<input type="button" value="&#x1f4f7" id="addImage" />
<input type="button" value="&#x2026" id="addImageLink" />
<input type="file" id="my_file" />    


$("#addImage").click(function () {
    document.getElementById('my_file').click();
    var x = document.getElementById("my_file").value;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
    wrapText("<img src=" + '"' + x + '"' + '>')
});
```

Comment: check the console output on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwbe8k3p/) to see exactly what is happening

Comment: Cool, this really helped me understand what was going on. Thank you